# Bayes Rule. Given I flipped 10 heads in a row, what is likelihood I own a double headed coin?

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes

$$\Pr(A | B) = \frac{\Pr(B | A) \Pr(A)}{\Pr(B)}$$

So my $\Pr(A)$ is probability that a coin is double headed. For the sake of argument let's say 1 in 10,000 coins are double headed.

My $\Pr(B)$ is the probability of flipping 10 heads, which is 1 in $2^{10}$.

So naively I thought $\Pr(B|A)$ well the probability that I flip 10 heads given that I have a double headed coin is 1?

That leaves the probability that I have a double headed coin at $\frac{10^{-4}}{2^{-10}}$.

However this means that the probability will be > 1 for larger flips.

The step in which I have made a mistake is evaluating $\Pr(B|A)$. Can anyone help?

Comment: Likelihood is not the same as probability. The probability of getting $k$ Heads in $10$ independent tosses of a coin that turns up Heads with probability $p$ is $\binom{10}{k}p^k(1-p)^{10-k}$. The _likelihood function_ of $p$ is $\binom{10}{k}p^k(1-p)^{10-k}$ where $p$ is the variable and $k$ is the number of Heads that have been observed; that is, the data.  In your case, the likelihood function of $p$ is $p^{10}, 0\leq p \leq 1$, which has a maximum value at $p=1$. To estimate $p$ via Bayes' theorem, you need to describe what you know about $p$. Are the other $9,999$ coins fair?

Comment: Yes they are fair, that is there is a 1 in 2 chance you will get a head

Comment: Your $P(B)$ is incorrect as it stands. $P(B)$ can be expanded to $P(B|A)\cdot P(A) + P(B|\overline{A})\cdot P(\overline{A})$.

Comment: So my P(B) should be 1*10^(-4) + (2^(-10) * (0.9999))

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @COOLSerdash for spotting my mistake

It was in my evaulation of $P(B)$ that I made the mistake.

I did not account for that fact the $P(B)$ the probability I flip 10 heads in a row is dependent on the fact that 1 in 10,000 coins are double headed.

When properly evaluating $P(B) = P(B|A)⋅P(A)+P(B|\overline{A})⋅P(\overline{A})$ I end up with a roughly 9% probability the coin is double headed if I get 10 heads in a row.

Plotting the number of heads on the $x$-axis, and the probability on the $y$-axis, looks quite beautiful:

[image: Coin Flip double headed graph]